# Change settings of custom jquery plugin using Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I create a very basic jquery plugin. Simply changing the with of the div. Now, I want to use knockoutjs to dynamically update the settings of that plugin. I cant seem to get my head around how to do this or even where to start. This is what I have so far.

```
<div class="mychart"></div>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: chartwidth"/>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: chartheight"/>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="knockout.js"></script>
  <script src="chartjs.js"></script>
  <script>

    $(".mychart").nbchart({
      width:'200px',
      height:'200px'
    });

    // Here's my data model
    var ViewModel = function(cwidth,cheight) {
        this.chartwidth = ko.observable(cwidth);
        this.chartheight= ko.observable(cheight);
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("100px","100px"));
```

Comment: Chances are the best way to do this in knockout would be to write a [binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for that jQuery plugin.  I feel doing so from scratch is a bit broad for a Stack Overflow answer though, but by all means take a look at writing a handler and asking more specific questions about that approach if you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing you could do is subscribe to the variables:

```
this.chartwidth.subscribe(function (newValue) {
  $(".mychart").nbchart({width:newValue});
});
```

However, you are violating the Cardinal Rule of Knockout, which is "Don't mess with the DOM outside of a binding handler."

A [custom binding handler](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html) for your plugin would look something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.nbchart = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    $(element).nbchart();
  },
  update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var config = ko.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).nbchart({
      width: config.width(),
      height: config.height()
    });
  }
};
```

and you would bind something like

```
<div data-bind="nbchart:config"></div>
```

where your viewmodel has a config variable like

```
var ViewModel = function(cwidth,cheight) {
    this.chartwidth = ko.observable(cwidth);
    this.chartheight= ko.observable(cheight);
    config: {
      width: this.chartwidth,
      height: this.chartheight
    }
};
```

Finally, if you are not planning to use the plugin without Knockout, you don't need a jQuery plugin. You can just write all the code as part of your custom binding handler.